# Calling a function in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new in Python and I am currently learning OOP in Pycharm.
When I type in a simple function like type(mylist), I dont see the answer in the console, I have to add print in the beginning, same with any other function, although in the tutorials I am currently following, they just call the function by typing its name and adding a parameter.
Same with my first attribute (please see screenshots)
Please help me if you know how to get around it.

[image]

Comment: are the using python 3.8 then, they are using  `print(my_dog:=Dog(mybreed='lab'))`

Comment: There are many ways to interpret python code in pycharm (avalibility may depends on version): terminal tool, python console tool, "run" tool e.t.c. Pycharm python console **in most** cases behaves like a regular python console but it's engine is something different. So if you think that you see something strange in your pycharm console you are able to check it in ordinary python console (that can be invoked by your system shell).

Comment: The basic rule for executing instructions in the console: if your instruction can be evaluated via built-in function `eval` then console prints the result of `repr(eval(your_instructions_here))`; if your instructions can be executed via built-in function `exec` then console just do `exec(your_instractions_here)`; in other cases you will see some error traceback. **But** there is a possibility to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the object instantiation from the `print()`

```
my_dog = Dog(mybreed='lab')
print(my_dog)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
`print(my_dog=Dog(mybreed='lab'))`
You could either split it to two lines:

```
my_dog = Dog(mybreed='lab')
print(my_dog)
```

Or, if you don't need the my_dog variable:

```
print(Dog(mybreed='lab'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python `variable_name = expression` can't be regarded as expression to be used as parameter, so `print(my_dog=Dog(mybreed='lab'))` will raise an error.

You can sure finish your job by this way:

```
my_dog = Dog(mybreed='lab')   # assign the variable my_dog
print(my_dog)                 # print the variable my_dog
```

If you don't need variable `my_dog`, you can just use `print(Dog(mybreed='lab'))`, which will surely work.

If you do prefer assign a variable and pass it as a parameter (just like C++ does), you can use Assignment Expressions(also The Walrus Operator) `:=` in Python 3.8 or higher version:
`print(my_dog:=Dog(mybreed='lab'))`

But just keep it in mind that this operator maybe not as convenient as you think!